# No phonegap based project template found while creating new xcode project

Tags: ios, cordova

I have to proceed with an existing phoengap application using phonegap 1.5 .
But when i am installing phonegap in my xcode 4.5.2 , I am not getting any option for "Phonegap based project" .
I am sure i have ios SDK and everything else required , but dont know what is wrong here .
Stucked in the same issue for weeks and no output.

Answer (score 5):

In th latest versions of PhoneGap, there wont be any template in XCode available. You need to use command line to create a new project. This link tells how to do it : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Check the **Project Creation** section.

Comment: in Xcode 5 same condition for me. Phonegap template not appear.